# How to find the size of a tensor in bytes?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Supposing I have a tensor named `encoding` which is of the shape `(1,32)` Now I would like to find out the *size* of the tensor in **bytes** not the shape of it. So basically I want to know how much memory it takes.

I found this StackOverflow question which does this exact thing but in TensorFlow 1. So how can I accomplish the same?? Here is the link ===> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966316/how-to-get-the-dimensions-of-a-tensor-in-tensorflow-at-graph-construction-time

> The SO question uses the `Tensorflow.contrib module` which (sadly) has been removed. So anyone know a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1** :
Get the **dtype** of the tensor. 
This will tell you about the number of bytes e.g.float64 is 64 bits = 8 Bytes.

**Step 2** 
Get the shape of the Tensor. 
This will give you the number of place-holders of the **dtype**. 
lets's assume shape = **m x n x p**

Count of the placeholders is C = m * n * p

Memory = 8 * C => Memory = **8 *m * n * p** Bytes.

See this excerpt from *Deep Learning with Python*, by **Francois Chollet**

> *A 60-second, 144 × 256 YouTube video clip sampled at 4 frames per second would have 240 frames. A batch of four such video clips would be stored in a tensor of shape (4, 240, 144, 256, 3). That’s a total of 106,168,320 values! If the dtype of the tensor was float32, then each value would be stored in 32 bits, so the tensor would represent 405 MB*

Comment: dtype of tensor is `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor` and the shape of the tensor is `TensorShape([None, 150, 100, 144])` But nowhere it mentions that it is float64 or not...

Comment: Which command you are using to get the dtype.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43978179/how-to-get-data-type-of-a-tensor-in-tensorflow

Comment: thanx, I got it. Mine is `float32` so it should have half the no. of bytes?

Comment: 32 bits = 4 Bytes.....Your total memory =  ~150*100*144*32 Bits......Please accept/+1 the answer if it helped. It helps the community to grow.

Answer (score 10):

To do this in a line of code, use:

`size_in_bytes = encoding.nelement() * encoding.element_size()`

This multiplies the number of elements in your tensor by the size of the tensor in bytes, to get the total memory usage of the tensor - not including the Python object overhead, which can be found with `sys.getsizeof()`.

Comment: That's for PyTorch, not TensorFlow.

Answer (score 1):

In Pytorch, you could use the following codes to get your tensor's memory occupation:

```
a = torch.rand(20, 30)
memory_size = sys.getsizeof(a) + torch.numel(a)*a.element_size()
print(f"Your tensor's memory_size:{memory_size}")
```

If you moved the tensor to GPU, then only sys.getsizeof(a) is in CPU memory, and torch.numel(a)*a.element_size() in GPU memory.